# How to avoid duplicate error when issuing delete and insert statement at the same table inside a trigger?

Tags: oracle, triggers

I have a trigger that modify a table by delete and insert at the same time. But I'm getting `ORA-00001: unique constraint violated`. I think the delete command did not actually commited yet before the insert command get fired, and because I can't use commit inside a trigger so I have no idea how to get away from that error.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "RESOURCEGROUP_AIU2" 
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE
ON resourcegroup
BEGIN
FOR ROW IN (SELECT *
             FROM resourcegroup_moves)
LOOP
  IF ROW.oldpath IS NOT NULL
  THEN
     DELETE FROM mayaccessflat 
      WHERE resourceGroup <> inheritedFrom
        AND resourcegroup = ROW.id
        AND inheritedFrom IN (SELECT id
                                FROM resourcegroup
                               WHERE ROW.oldpath LIKE path||'/%');
  END IF;
  INSERT INTO mayaccessflat
             (resourcegroup, person, PROFILE, inheritedfrom)
    SELECT DISTINCT ROW.ID, ma.person, ma.PROFILE, rg.ID
      FROM mayaccess ma, resourcegroup rg
     WHERE ma.resourcegroup = rg.ID
       AND ma.inherit=1
       AND ROW.newpath LIKE rg.PATH || '/%';
END LOOP;
END;
```

I'm using Oracle 6 DB.

Comment: *"I'm using Oracle 6 DB"* Hmmm, I would say congratulations on using such an ancient relic but I don't think you are using Oracle v6. Casting my mind back 25 years, although Oracle 6 allowed us to define constraints they weren't enforced: that didn't happen until Oracle 7. Likewise Oracle 6 didn't have triggers, they also arrived in Oracle 7.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is nothing to do with commit. The INSERT happens in the same transaction as the DELETE. Therefore the problem must be that the DELETE is not removing all the keys which are being INSERTED by the subsequent statement.

One reason for this might be that the records in `resourcegroup_moves` aren't internally consistent. Or they may not be consistent with the related records in `resourcegroup`. If so, the INSERT hurls ORA-00001 correctly and the solution is improved validation of `resourcegroup_moves`.

Alternatively, maybe the **set** of records in `resourcegroup_moves` is valid but the inconsistency arises because you're processing those records row-by-row rather than as a set. Your use of DISTINCT won't solve this because you're not handling the whole set. If this is the case a set-based approach might solve it:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "RESOURCEGROUP_AIU2" 
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE
ON resourcegroup
BEGIN
  DELETE FROM mayaccessflat 
  WHERE resourceGroup <> inheritedFrom
  AND (resourcegroup, inheritedFrom) IN 
            (SELECT rgm.id, rg.id
             FROM resourcegroup_moves rgm, 
                   resourcegroup rg
              WHERE rgm.oldpath LIKE rg.path||'/%');

  INSERT INTO mayaccessflat
             (resourcegroup, person, PROFILE, inheritedfrom)
    SELECT DISTINCT rgm.ID, ma.person, ma.PROFILE, rg.ID
      FROM mayaccess ma
           , resourcegroup rg
           , resourcegroup_moves rgm
     WHERE ma.resourcegroup = rg.ID
       AND ma.inherit=1
       AND rgm.newpath LIKE rg.PATH || '/%';
END;
```

---

Putting this sort of business logic in a trigger not good practice. It would be better as a stored procedure where you could apply validation rules to `resourcegroup` and `resourcegroup_moves`.

Answer (score 0):

You should set your unique constraint as `DEFERRABLE` and then use `SET CONSTRAINTS name DEFERRED` inside the transaction to defer the unique check until the transaction is comitted.

See [Specifying Constraint State](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/clauses002.htm) in the Orcale docs.